Why does packet arrival increases increases exponentially when sending rate goes to link capacity?

This is from kurose and ross pdf's page 302 - 304. no error recovery (for example, in retransmission), flow control, or congestion control is considered in this case.
So what is the reason for exponential increase in delay?

Please check the title.

(What do you expect? What is R/2?)
